# getInboxThreads() for specific inbox folder. Google Apps Script gmail

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, google-inbox

I am trying to retrieve email threads from only a specific folder which I named 'Approval_needed'. I have found a way to get all of my inbox threads like so from the [Google Apps Script Reference page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getInboxThreads()):

```
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
 for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
   Logger.log(threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject());
 }
```

Is it possible to do something like `getInboxThreads for folder 'Approval_needed'`?
I have searched around and have not found an answer for this. I have found other methods such as `getPriorityInboxThreads()` and `getStarredInboxThreads()`, but nothing like `getInboxThreads(string)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are calling "folder" is actually a "label" in gmail, you can use the [getThreads()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label#getThreads()) method on the [Label](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label) class.

Example from the documentation :

```
// Log the subject lines of the threads labeled with MyLabel
 var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("MyLabel");
 var threads = label.getThreads();
 for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
   Logger.log(threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject());
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I actually google'd "What is a label in google apps script?" and the answer I found was "A user-created label in a user's Gmail account." followed by some label methods. So I wasn't exactly sure what that was for.